# I need to password protect the entire computer

Tags: windows-xp, passwords

Everything I open needs to ask for a password. What software will help do do this task? I am using Windows XP 32 bit.

Answer: I right-clicked any .EXE I wanted to prompt me a password -> Advanced -> Checked off "Run with different credentials".

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: The computer is supposed to be locked down from anything except Mozilla Firefox and Internet Explorer. This computer is for business.

Comment: I recommend you use local security policy or group policy rather than password protection if you're trying to lock the system down.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: looks like he is setting up a kiosk for internet browsing center ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my own problem.

What I did was right click any .EXE I wanted to prompt me a password -> Advanced -> Checked off "Run with different credentials". Easy fix that anyone could have figured out if they took the time to think a little!

[image]

Comment: Great. I'll install my own software and run that just fine. Group Policy is the way to go here.

Answer (score 6):

I recommend using local security policies to lock down a user account, rather than password protecting everything.  Creating a highly restricted user should be sufficient.

http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/wxppspol.html is a quick guide to getting started with local security policies.  You should be able to create a user account and then tailor it to your security needs.  There are many more settings than shown in that article, and through a combination of security policy and permissions you should be able to create a totally locked down user.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just set a BIOS boot password? That way nobody can even boot up into Windows without authenticating.

---

After your comment, it seems setting up a kiosk solution would be better if only browsers will be accessed. Since it's using multiple browsers, you could use 1 account per browser or set up a hotkey to switch browsers.

You can start up IE with the **-k** switch for kiosk mode.

For Firefox, look into [the R-kiosk add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1659) (only supported up to FF 3.1b3 though unfortunately).

Certain keyboard shortcuts still work in some of the kiosk modes, you can combat the possibilities with [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to remap any combinations you'd like, and even create a very complex combination to unlock it if you need to change something. Of course you can take extra security measures with group policies, and create a backup in case some crafty fellow manages to bypass everything.

---

For a fairly cheap software solution ($10), [WinGuard Pro](http://www.winguardpro.com/) does what you want. There is a free version as well but it is fairly limited in functionality.

[image]

Comment: I just need to password protect everything except Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Comment: That would get very complicated. Their caches would need to write to the disk in certain locations among other things. Consider kiosk options if only browsers need to be accessed, that's the whole idea behind a kiosk environment.

Comment: Kiosk is not an option.

Comment: Any reason why? If people will only be accessing browsers it's kind of detrimental to your goal to do this another way. And why are 2 browsers needed out of curiosity? =S

Comment: Not my business, I am doing the job for somebody and this is what they told me to do.

Comment: Alright, well I added another software solution if you're interested.

Comment: I think that will do. I will test it and give u the results.

Comment: I am currently trying to test out AxCrypt.

Comment: tell me how it goes!

Comment: AxCrpyt made it worse, I think I am going to go with phoebus's suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is for you:

> **[PC Security™](http://www.tropsoft.com/pcsecurity/index.htm)** is the ultimate computer security system offering File
>   Lock, Folder Lock, System Lock,
>   Shortcut/Program Lock, Explorer
>   Control, Context Menu, Restricted
>   System, Window Lock, Intruder
>   Detection with Alarm, Import and
>   Export PC Security settings, Flexible
>   and complete password protection, and
>   Drag and Drop support.

[image]

**Shortcut/Program Lock:**

[image]

**File Lock:**

[image]

**Folder Lock:**

[image]

*PC Security™ is shareware ($44.95), try before you buy.*

Comment: Thats exactly what I want but is there any free alternative?

Comment: not that i know of, but you said it's for business so 45 bucks shouldn't hurt you too much :)

Comment: This is not my business, I am doing the job for somebody, shareware is not an option.

Comment: Don't do work for businesses that can't/won't pay $45 for software.  You will probably not get paid either.

Comment: they can evaluate it for 60 days and if this piece of software does exactly what they want and they don't want to cough up $45 ... what can i say? :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Windows Steady State](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/sharedaccess/default.mspx). It makes it fairly easy to lock down a computer, and you can use it in conjunction with local security policies.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you're asking for full disk encryption.  You'll need to enter a password once when the computer boots, but nothing will be accessible until you do and you will not need to enter it again.  It's a little more practical than encrypting every file individually.

Check out [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/).  Be careful, though; if you lose your password or mess something up, you could permanently lose your data.

If this isn't the case, state your needs a little more clearly.